# How to code: if (e.ChangeType == 'Created') do something, when using FileSystemWatcher?

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

My goal is to code the following.. `If` change type is `created` do this, `if` it is `deleted` do that. How is this done?

This is what I have tried..

```
private static void directoryChange(object source, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{e.ChangeType} - {e.FullPath} - {System.Environment.NewLine}");

    if (e.ChangeType == "Created")
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

But an error shows up:

Operator `==` cannot be applied to operands of type `WatcherChangeTypes` and `string`

I have also tried

```
if (e.ChangeTypeEquals("Created"){
}
```

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: Maybe because you did not do a research before asking? A simple look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemeventargs.changetype?view=netframework-4.8) or even moving the mouse over the property e.ChangeType would have told you what kind of type is expected here

Comment: @SirRufo i was looking at wrong section that's why then https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: your link is different to mine?

Comment: Yes, I know - but where in that section did you read, it is of type string?

Comment: Even IntelliSense will tell you while typing what kind of type it is expected here - see [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/iylixka)

Comment: I see.. you're right. I will spend more time into looking at little details. Thanks for your comments :)

Answer (score 3):

Please replace `"Created"` by `System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Created`